# I'm struggling to pass a List<CameraDescription> as path parameters in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

The encoded value used in the path parameter is causing the camera to fail to open.
[Issue picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckxxp.png)

Here I encode the **List** using **JSON** to **String**:
[Method where converting List to String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WJ4O.png)

Here is the **go_router code snippets** in which I **decoded** this **String**:
[go_router code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C5vA.png)

I have tried other methods, like **split** and **join**, but they didn't work.

Comment: check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html - they say: "If value contains objects that are not directly encodable to a JSON string (a value that is not a number, boolean, string, null, list or a map with string keys), the `toEncodable` function is used to convert it to an object that must be directly encodable.

If `toEncodable` is omitted, it defaults to a function that returns the result of calling `.toJson()` on the unencodable object."